Automated file reconstruction from multiple copies
I would like to automate the repair (on Linux) of a variety of different file types. In many cases, I have multiple copies of a file, from backups. In other cases, I may have only one copy. I can certainly do this manually, by examining contents, possibly using repair tools. Manual repair is impractical when there are more than a handful to be fixed.
Let's use mp3 files as a concrete example; but this question applies to all (common) file types, such as tar files, git repos, you-name-it.  Fifteen years ago, I copied 3300 mp3 files from one computer to another. Both computers run mdraid disk mirroring and ext4fs. They sat there, more-or-less untouched, for all that time. I recently discovered that 683 of these files have differences (as reported by diff -r -q) Examining a handful of these shows minor variations in file sizes. Examining them with audacity shows "normal-looking" audio envelopes, and both variants can be played to the end. Both sound good, have no blips or obvious audio defects, other than maybe a "beep" in one of them, lasting less than a tenth of second, or less.  That is, both variants are OK for listening.
I can search for long sequences of zero-bytes, using e.g. grep -Pal '\x00{512}' <filename> and I discover 450 (of the 680) have sequences of 512 consecutive null bytes in them. About 550 have sequences of 128 consecutive null bytes, but only 8 have runs of 4096 null bytes. Using the mp3val confirms that there are issues, and sometimes, both copies of a file have issues (but since both copies differ, presumably these issues are in different places).
I posed the above for mp3's. However, I have 1.5 million files, of which 99.999% are NOT mp3's. These include tar files and git repos and great-great-grandma's photos and ... whatever. Of these, I discovered that 1440 files consist of nothing but zeros (and obviously shouldn't, e.g. tar files) In many cases, I have backups, maybe even 3 or 4 or 6 backups. Some of newer backups might contain corrupted data. A majority of the (more recent) backups might contain corrupted data! An old backup of a corrupted git tree is "better than nothing", but the latest git tree is best.
How do I recover valid data, on an industrial scale, after decades of silent corruption?
(Footnote: for the future, I am looking at Ceph. It has a "deep scrubbing" feature, which is "like fsck", runs once a week (by default) and uses 3 copies of a file (by default). Fingers crossed that I can trust it. But after the above saga, I don't know what I can trust. Obviously not the current combo of mdraid, ext4 and consumer-grade pc's, disks and controllers.)

The main problem with your question for THIS site is that the METHOD for recovering usable data is largely file-type dependent. Repairing an MP3 is one thing, repairing a tar is something else, and repairing  a folder structure full of text files (a git repo) is something else. While there are general principles, there are already questions on this site regarding general data recovery principles. I recommend that you focus on a single file type you need assistance performing recover on, if your question isn't answered by the generic data recovery answers already here.

Hi @music2myear Thanks. The issue is that I have dozens of file types, and thousands of damaged files. Fixing one file type is nice, but then there are 23 other types. Simply finding all the damage is a chore.  Apache Tika will identify and validate; it does not do repair, as far as I can tell. I'm still exploring. IBM offers a multi-million dollar solution. I was hoping for an open-source equivalent.
